# Stacking section labels in left margin

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I am starting to convert to LaTeX to do my homework for Math courses. I want to use sectioning to separate questions

```
\section{5.3}
\subsection{1}
\subsubsection{a}
```

and look something like this:

[image]

I tried to use `titlesec` to put the section labels in the margin but I can't stack them like I want. Any help?

Comment: If you're placing *numbers* as your section "title", then you're better off using an enumeration; for this you should consider the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Comment: Are you interested in manually labelling content the way you're doing? Or is it that the list will not follow each other in some form of sequence (numerically/alphabetically)?

Comment: @Werner Yes I want to be able to skip labels

Comment: @TwiNight even if you like this you can always use \addtocounter{CTR}{somme value}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the assumption that you want total manual control over the list items, the following `homework` environment should suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\newsection}[1]{\gdef\seclab{#1\gdef\seclab{}}}
\newcommand{\newsubsection}[1]{\gdef\subseclab{#1\gdef\subseclab{}}}
\newcommand{\newsubsubsection}[1]{\gdef\subsubseclab{#1\gdef\subsubseclab{}}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{homework}[1][1.5em]
  {% \begin{homework}
   \addtolength{\@totalleftmargin}{#1}% Accommodate wide labels
   \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textbf{\seclab~\subseclab\subsubseclab}}%
   \begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}}% \end{homework}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{homework}
  \newsection{5.3}
  \newsubsection{1}
  \newsubsubsection{a}

  \item Solution to question 1a.

    blah blah blah \ldots

  \newsubsubsection{b}

  \item Solution to question 1b.

    blah blah blah \ldots

  \newsubsection{2}
  \newsubsubsection{a}

  \item Solution to question 2a.

    blah blah blah \ldots

  \newsubsubsection{b}

  \item Solution to question 2b.

    blah blah blah \ldots
\end{homework}

\end{document}
```

The `homework` environment takes an optional argument that you can use to push the entire list over to the right, in case your section labels become too big and roll over into the left margin (they are right-aligned).

Comment: Have to do some tweaking but get me where I wanted. Thanks